# How did Mirza Ghulam Ahmad make people follow him?

Tags: miracles, ahmadiyyah

There are around 10-20 million Ahmadiyyas in the world. What made people follow the founder of the Ahmadiyya movement, Mirza Ghulam Ahmad? If a person randomly says that he is the Messiah, no one will believe him so what made Ahmadiyyas follow Mirza Ghulam Ahmad?

Comment: I wonder how this is related to Islam?

Comment: Because it links to the claim that he made that he was the Messiah of ISLAM.

Comment: IMO this is off-topic and would be a better fit for history SE.